# Recording and writing voice data as String in a file for Encryption

Tags: python, audio, encryption, aes, audio-recording

I have written the AES for data encryption, my code is capable of encryption Text files while picking 32 bytes at a time...I now want to encrypt the recorded voice as well,

this is what I have done so far,

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "R_Voice.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("The Voice is being Recorded........")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print (frames)
f = open("abc.txt",'w')
f.write(str(frames))
f.close()
```

The `frames[]` consist of the Hexadecimal data of the recorded voice i wanted to write this data into a file as a string so i did this (as shown above)

```
 f.write(str(frames))
```

but when I see the data in the file `abc.txt` after executing the program, it is in this form, and complete data is in a single line which usually hangs my Raspberry Pi.

```
['7\xe47\xe4O\xe4O\xe4N\xe4N\xe4A\xe4A\xe4F\xe4F\xe4C\xe4C\xe4H\xe4H\xe4Y\x
```

How am i supposed to convert it to the string so that i could encrypt it ?

Comment: Looks like python so I tagged it as such. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you're storing the input data as text represention. You need to save it as-is : f = open("abc.txt",'wb') ; f.write(frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
with open("filename", 'w') as outFile:
  for frame in frames:
    outFile.write(frame)
```

to concatenate all frames as byte stream into that file.

Comment: Btw: No need to `close` the file if you are using `with` to `open` it.  `with` takes care of that.